# HTML5 textarea placeholder not appearing

Tags: jquery, forms, html, textarea, placeholder

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my markup, but the placeholder for the text area will not appear. It seems as though it may be covered up with some blank spaces and tabs. When you focus on the text area and delete from where the cursor puts itself, then leave the text area, the proper placeholder then appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="message.php" method="post" id="message_form">
        <fieldset>

            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="Email address"
                maxlength="40"
                placeholder="Email Address" 
                autocomplete="off" required />
            <br />
            <input type="text" 
                name="subject" 
                id="subject" title="Subject"
                maxlength="60" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off" required />
            <br />
            <textarea name="message" 
                id="message" 
                title="Message" 
                cols="30" 
                rows="5" 
                maxlength="100" 
                placeholder="Message" required>
            </textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit"/>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#message_form').html5form({
        allBrowsers : true,
        responseDiv : '#response',
        messages: 'en',
        messages: 'es',
        method : 'GET',
        colorOn :'#d2d2d2',
        colorOff :'#000'
    }
);
});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3BzBk/ ... Dont place the script outside the body :)

Comment: Which browser are you using? Not all browsers support the placeholder attribute

Comment: You can always use the onfocus and onblur events to get the same effect. Also, you can test if placeholder is supported by the browser or not by using a function like:

function placeholderIsSupported() {
    test = document.createElement('input');
    return ('placeholder' in test);
}

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen Thank you! I cannot yet tell exactly what is different but it works now.

Comment: @user1338065 Super. Was it because it was placed outside the body or?

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen That, and it had something to do with my formatting of the code. I had the <form> indented, but when I align it flush to the left edge (no indent), it works. With indents, it goes back to not showing.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen Can I add another question? What do I need to do to have the place holder text switch to a lighter text style when the input becomes active?

Comment: Seems the `colorOn` `colorOff` setting in html5form you defined are working fine? :)

Comment: I'd also suggest you start using the html5 Doctype.
<!doctype html>

Answer (score 869, accepted):

This one has always been a gotcha for me and many others.  In short, the opening and closing tags for the `<textarea>` element must be on the same line, otherwise a newline character occupies it.  The placeholder will therefore not be displayed since the input area contains content (a newline character is, technically, valid content).

Good:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Bad:

```
<textarea>
</textarea>
```

### Update (2020)

This is [not true](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody:parse-errors-35) anymore, according to the HTML5 parsing spec:

```
If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, 
then ignore that token and move on to the next one. (Newlines 
at the start of textarea elements are ignored as an authoring 
convenience.)
```

You might still have trouble if you editor insists on ending lines with CRLF, though.

Comment: If the plugin was edited, you can fix this issue using jQuery's [`.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method.

Comment: An example, would be to simply add a piece to JS (before or after plugin call, doesn't matter) that looks like the following: `$('textarea'),each(function(i) { if ($.trim($(this).text()) == '') $(this).text('').trigger('blur'); });`

Comment: Also, when creating a new textarea element after the DOM is loaded, make sure to include the closing tag `/>` instead of `>`. Example: `$('body').html('<textarea placeholder="test" />');`

Comment: if there is a whitespace inside the `<textarea>` it means that the textarea isn't empty, so, there is no use for a placeholder. :)

Comment: any idea how i make sure the `textarea` always has enough lines for "overflow" or excessive input? i.e. how can i make the rows increase as the input increases?

Comment: Ridiculous that this was the issue

Comment: This answer is outdated in [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody:parse-errors-35)  "If the next token is a U+000A LINE FEED (LF) character token, then ignore that token and move on to the next one. (Newlines at the start of textarea elements are ignored as an authoring convenience.)"

Comment: @Mrten I dont know about that but the solution still helped me because I had to delete a space unless it was not working

Comment: This solved the issue for me - 2021, angular 9

Comment: Textarea content set and get with val property, but any between tags is treated as textarea content. 
Whoever invented this miracle - you have very sophisticated mind, mister

Comment: still true in 2024

Answer (score 71):

**Delete all spaces and line breaks between `<textarea>` opening and closing `</textarea>` tags.**

```
<textarea placeholder="YOUR TEXT"></textarea>  ///Correct one

<textarea placeholder="YOUR TEXT"> </textarea>  ///Bad one It's treats as a value so browser won't display the Placeholder value

<textarea placeholder="YOUR TEXT"> 
</textarea>  ///Bad one
```

Comment: The space kills it? Weird.

Comment: It treats space as a value.

Answer (score 12):

its because there is a space somewhere. I was using jsfiddle and there was a space after the  tag. After I deleted the space it started working

Comment: Wow! I had the closing textarea tag on the next line, indented 4 spaces > those invisible spaces are in the textarea, but I didn't realize that until I tried to use placeholder. No spaces between the opening and closing textarea tags!

Answer (score 5):

Well, technically it does not have to be on the same line as long as there is no character between the ending ">" from start tag and the starting "<" from the closing tag.  That is you need to end with 
`...></textarea>` as in the example below:

```
<p><label>Comments:<br>
       <textarea id = "comments" rows = "4" cols = "36" 
            placeholder = "Enter comments here"
            class = "valid"></textarea>
    </label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this post has been (very well) answered by  Aquarelle but just in case somebody is having this issue with other tag forms with no text such as inputs i'll leave this here:

If you have an input in your form and placeholder is not showing because a white space at the beginning, this may be caused for you "value" attribute. In case you are using variables to fill the value of an input check that there are no white spaces between the commas and the variables.

example using twig for php framework symfony :

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="{{ subject }}" placeholder="hello" />       <-- this is ok
<input type="text" name="subject" value" {{ subject }} " placeholder="hello" />      <-- this will not show placeholder
```

In this case the tag between {{ }} is the variable, just make sure you are not leaving spaces between the commas because white space is also a valid character.

Answer (score 3):

use `<textarea></textarea>` instead of leaving a space between the opening and closing tags as `<textarea>
</textarea>`

Comment: This adds nothing that the existing answers don't already address.

Answer (score 1):

Between the opening and closing tag in our case textarea tag shouldn't be **space** or **newline character** or any text(value).

If there's space, newline character or any text, it's considered as value which overrides placeholder.

```
    **PlaceHolder Appears**
    <textarea placeholder="Am Default Message"></textarea>

    **PlaceHolder Doesn't Appear**

    <textarea placeholder="Am Default Message">  </textarea>
   <textarea placeholder="Am Default Message"> 
   </textarea>
   <textarea placeholder="Am Default Message">Something</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only using a `.pug` file (similar to `.jade`). I realized that it was also a **space issue**, following the end of my closing parentheses. In my example, you need to highlight the text after `(placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE")` to see:

**BEFORE:**

```
form.form-horizontal(method='POST')
  .form-group
    textarea.form-control(placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE") 
  .form-group  
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') SUBMIT
```

**AFTER:**

```
form.form-horizontal(method='POST')
  .form-group
    textarea.form-control(placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE")
  .form-group  
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') SUBMIT
```