# HTML forms: display a text in an input (textarea)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that I pre-fill with my database data. It is working perfectly for all my input. I have a text (that I enter in my database using a textarea). But when I am using the following the text does show in the text area (if I change it to input it is working but I do not have several lines and column allowed with textarea)

```
<textarea 
    rows="4"
    class="form-control" 
    name="roster_description" 
    id="roster_description" 
    placeholder =
        <?php if ($description_roster){
                echo '"'.$description_roster.'"'; 
            } else {
                echo "";
            }?>>
</textarea>
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of your PHP?

Comment: this is a shot in the dark, remove that newline, and put it in one line instead: `?>></textarea>` maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585759/why-isnt-my-textareas-placeholder-showing-up

Comment: This code should work. Can you post the code before the `textarea` definition?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn $description_roster is a string 'a team composed of players'

Comment: Not a solution, but you might want to [escape the description](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) first, in case you have a description like `Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson`.

Comment: @cloudfeet actually that's a very good point. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it and it works:

```
<textarea 
    rows="4"
    class="form-control" 
    name="roster_description" 
    id="roster_description" 
    placeholder = "<?php if ($description_roster) echo $description_roster;?>">
</textarea>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem. Also the question had a check if `description_roster` exists which is a good thing. So your solution is worser then the question self.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that your statement:

```
echo "";
```

doesn't produce quotation marks - it produces the empty string.  What you want is to replace this with:

```
echo '""';
```

which will produce `placeholder="">` instead of `placeholder=>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok no clue why but the following is working:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="description_roster" 
          name="description_roster" rows="4"
          placeholder=<?php
                         if ($description_roster){
                             echo '"'.$description_roster.'"';
                         } else {
                             echo "";
                         }
                       ?>
></textarea>
```

Thanks to those who had a look