# jQuery editable add plecholder text

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, textarea

I have a text that when it's clicked, it becomes a textarea using the editable function from js. How can I add a placeholder text to that area? i tried to search it in the dom using $('textarea') but I had no luck. I also use backbone model and view to generate the views.

Comment: can we get some example html coming out of this? it will help with the selector accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll update the selector in a bit, but right now this will work:

$("form :text").attr("placeholder",what you want);

html gotcha, make sure the `<textarea></textarea>` are on the same line, otherwise "\n" will be the default value regardless of the placeholder [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186913/html5-textarea-placeholder-not-appearing).