# Textarea Placeholder is not working

Tags: html

I have written the below textarea code and the placeholder is not working. I can't see the placeholder on the textarea box.

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Current Address">
</textarea>
```

Comment: You might be having the same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186913/html5-textarea-placeholder-not-appearing#14048003

Comment: please provide your code what have tried

Comment: OP has added code but hasn't converted it to **code**

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186913/html5-textarea-placeholder-not-appearing

Comment: Looks good **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/s1ta8o16/)**

Comment: @DDan is right, you textarea has content (a line break). So it shows the content instead of the placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't keep gap between start and end tag `<textarea></textarea>`

use this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Current Address"></textarea>
```

[W3School Example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_placeholder.asp)

The reason that this works is because the newline character in between the `textarea` tags is considered content, so it is placed inside the box instead of the placeholder.