# Jade placeholder is not appearing in the textarea tag

Tags: html, pug, placeholder

I am using Jade and I want to use a placeholder in a textarea, I place the placeholder tag the same way that I'm doing with an input, but it doesn't seem to work, here's my textarea.

```
textarea(id="instructionsText" name="instructions_text", cols="60", rows="10" placeholder="Instructions for the survey (Optional)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was correct, the problem was that I have a whitespace after the textarea tag, I guess that Jade translate that whitespace as the content of the textarea. Here is the question that kind of helped me out [HTML5 textarea placeholder not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186913/html5-textarea-placeholder-not-appearing)